# Android Eclipse sometimes blocks my pc when editing source code

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

Sometimes when editing source code (specially with some code autocompletion) my computer gets blocked and I need to reboot the system. This occurs with specific cases for example:

In the following snippet:

```
 dateNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
```

when I was trying to erase "HOUR_OF_DAY" in order to change it to another field my computer get blocked.

It is strange because I reboot the system and when I try to delete the same code, it blocks my pc again.

The eclipse log file shows the following:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2014-03-17 11:52:17.255
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.conditionalArgumentsIncompatibleTypes(ProblemReporter.java:1401)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConditionalExpression.resolveType(ConditionalExpression.java:569)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.BinaryExpression.resolveType(BinaryExpression.java:1787)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CombinedBinaryExpression.resolveType(CombinedBinaryExpression.java:337)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:243)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:507)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:259)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:466)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1162)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1272)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:561)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I am working with: 
Ubuntu 12.04
Eclipse for android
Android Developer Tools
Build: v22.3.0-887826
Java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the error log I found another report that helps me to solve the problem (This reduced the frequency of crashes but it continues happening):

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-19 10:56:06.350
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git.        Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

Then what I have done is to install git in my Ubuntu Operating System:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

Another error that I can see in the error log is the following:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 4 0 2014-04-02 19:24:14.325
!MESSAGE Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event  [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/ElementContainer/selectedElement/SET] to handler  org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler@1ea92ae
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to     org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.EHandlerService
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.MenuHelper$1.evaluate(MenuHelper.java:240)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ContributionsAnalyzer.isVisible(ContributionsAnalyzer.java:248)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarContributionRecord.computeVisibility(ToolBarContributionRecord.java:114)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarContributionRecord.updateVisibility(ToolBarContributionRecord.java:68)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer$6.changed(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:352)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:110)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:328)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:342)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext$1.changed(EclipseContext.java:738)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:110)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:328)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.setParent(EclipseContext.java:399)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.showElementRecursive(LazyStackRenderer.java:254)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.showElementRecursive(LazyStackRenderer.java:279)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.showElementRecursive(LazyStackRenderer.java:285)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.showElementRecursive(LazyStackRenderer.java:285)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.showElementRecursive(LazyStackRenderer.java:285)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.showTab(LazyStackRenderer.java:158)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:109)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:67)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4299)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:1)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.perspectiveswitcher.PerspectiveSwitcher$13.widgetSelected(PerspectiveSwitcher.java:439)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```